# Merge rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Part of a csv-file ('data.csv') I have to process, looks like this:

```
parent_id,parent_name,Type,Companyname,Custsupid,Streetaddress
3,Customer,,,C0010,
3,Customer,A,,,
3,Customer,,ACE SYSTEMS,,
3,Customer,,,,Straat 10
7,Customer,,,Q8484,
7,Customer,B,,,
7,Customer,,XYZ AUTOMAT,,
7,Customer,,,,Laan 99
```

To import this file into a dataframe I do:

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv').fillna('')

This results in:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| |parent_id|parent_name|Type|Companyname|Custsupid|Streetaddress|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|0|3        |Customer   |    |           |C0010    |             |
|1|3        |Customer   |A   |           |         |             |
|2|3        |Customer   |    |ACE SYSTEMS|         |             |
|3|3        |Customer   |    |           |         |Straat 10    |
|4|7        |Customer   |    |           |Q8484    |             |
|5|7        |Customer   |B   |           |         |             |
|6|7        |Customer   |    |XYZ AUTOMAT|         |             |
|7|7        |Customer   |    |           |         |Laan 99      |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, what I want to end up with, is a dataframe that looks like  this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| |parent_id|parent_name|Type|Companyname|Custsupid|Streetaddress|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|0|3        |Customer   |A   |ACE SYSTEMS|C0010    |Straat 10    |
|1|7        |Customer   |B   |XYZ AUTOMAT|Q8484    |Laan 99      |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I already tried with df.groupby etc. but I can't produce the desired result.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [37]: df.groupby(['parent_id', 'parent_name']).sum()
Out[37]: 
                      Type  Companyname Custsupid Streetaddress
parent_id parent_name                                          
3         Customer       A  ACE SYSTEMS     C0010     Straat 10
7         Customer       B  XYZ AUTOMAT     Q8484       Laan 99
```

`sum` is adding strings together, and thus this relies on the fact that adding empty strings to a non-empty string returns the non-empty string.