# Merge rows in dataframe and keep other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python with pandas

I have a Dataframe :

```
   id title_fr lang title_en  title_de
0   1   maison   fr      NaN       NaN
1   1      NaN   en    house       NaN
2   1      NaN   de      NaN     hause
```

The expected output is simple, I want to merge rows with same id, and keep field not null :

```
   id title_fr lang title_en  title_de
0   1   maison   fr    house     hause
```

I tried with groupby function, but this is not working

I tried this (see [Merge rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499819/merge-rows-in-dataframe)) :

```
x = [
    {"id": 1, "title_fr": "maison", "lang": "fr"},
    {"id": 1, "title_en": "house", "lang": "en"},
    {"id": 1, "title_de": "maisonen", "lang": "de"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=x)
df = df.groupby(['id']).sum()
```

But I got this ouput :

```
      lang
id        
1   frende
```

Comment: Use `first` to ignore NaNs `df.groupby('id').first()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) - but it return always first non `NaN`s values per groups, so `en` with `de` for `lang` are removed:

```
df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
print (df)
   id title_fr lang title_en  title_de
0   1   maison   fr    house  maisonen
```